# Код элемента сохранение

Tags: html

Есть сайт, который мне не принадлежит. Меняю код через просмотр кода элемента, нужно, чтобы после нажатия кнопки "Перезагрузить" изменения сохранялись. Асолютно любые способы, то есть должно быть ощущение, что страница перезагружается и на ней действительно соответствующая информация.

Comment: Я, честно говоря, не очень в этом разбираюсь, тут люди как-то в хроме меняют, и после обновления страницы все сохраняется, а что такое фф?

Comment: мне это нужно для сьемки видео, как я захожу в личный кабинет и демонстрирую то что происходит на странице, но на немного измененной странице )

Comment: @DDd, классический пример мошенника...

Comment: html сохраните через ctrl + s, или выкачаете через httrack. 

И после этого залейте все на вируальный сервер, дайте там домен, повесьте его через host-ы. 

Это самый простой способ.

@TheDoctor Похоже на то..)

Comment: нет, вы не правы, школьный проэкт. а где купить этот вирт сервер и домен?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Знаю, что для ff есть какой-то плагин, который позволяет дописывать css для сайта и запоминает его.

Но с хтмл - думаю, это не реально.

Answer (score 1):

Это, в принципе, реально.
Написать небольшой аддон для целевого браузера, установить его и он будет вставлять что надо при заходе на сайт. Но только там, где этот аддон установлен.

Другой вопрос - нужно ли это? Как-то сомнительная надобность выходит :)

Comment: Да все в принципе реально. Я, видать, не правильно выразился. Вряд ли есть сейчас подобное решение. Никому такое, как правило, не нужно. =)